# Sort mapped array in Easy Mapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, class

I have a class like below:

```
@interface GroupStandings : NSObject<EKMappingProtocol>
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString* groupName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* standingList;
@end
```

and a mapping like:

```
+(EKObjectMapping *)objectMapping
{
    return [EKObjectMapping mappingForClass:self  withBlock:^(EKObjectMapping *mapping) {
    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"GroupName" toProperty:@"groupName"];
    [mapping hasMany:[StandingsTeam class] forKeyPath:@"StandingList" forProperty:@"standingList"];
}];
}
```

In StandingsTeam class, I have a property called points and I want to sort "standingList" as soon as I take it from object mapping.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Override the setter for the `standingList` property, to sort during assignment:

```
- (void)setStandingList:(NSArray *)standingList
{
    _standingList = [standingList sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
}
```

Note: there are many ways to sort the array.

Comment: Thank you very much. what on earth I could not think this :)